# How to Proof parameter in php

Tags: php, validation, coding-style

Hy!

I have a user_register php with a few parameter and they all should be proofed. My format is very ugly. I packed all my validations in intricated if clauses.

Take a look:

```
include '../db_connect.php';
$arr = array('Data' => null,'Code' => null);

$birthdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birth']);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pw']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$lang = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lang']);

if (!proof_value($birthdate) && !proof_value($gender) && !proof_value($uname) && !proof_value($password) && !proof_value($email))
{
    if (!user_exist($uname))
    {
        if(!email_exist($email))
        {
            if (count($pw)==32)
            {
                    if(count($gender)==1 && ($gender=='m' ||$gender =='f'))
                    {
                        $code = genverification();
                        $sql = "Insert into USER (DATE_BIRTH,GENDER,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL,VERIFICATION) VALUES ('$birthdate','$gender','$uname','$password','$email','$code')";
                        $result = mysql_query("Insert into USER (DATE_BIRTH,GENDER,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL,VERIFICATION) VALUES ('$birthdate','$gender','$uname','$password','$email','$code')");
                        if ($result)
                        {
                            require_once("mailer.php");
                            if (sendmail($email,$link, $lang))
                            {
                                $arr['Code'] = 200;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $arr['Code'] = 422;
                            }


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $arr['Code'] = 421;
                            //$arr['Date'] = $sql;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $arr['Code'] = 420;
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                $arr['Code']=423;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            $arr['Code']=419;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        $arr['Code']=418;
    }

}
else
{
$arr['Code']=400;
}

mysql_close($db);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

As you can see if a validation fails my script will return a error code. I want to change my actuall format to a better readable format but i have now idea how to solve this otherwise

Thx

Comment: `My format is very ugly.` Yes, it is.

Comment: if thos user functions are just returning `isset()`'s then why not just use `isset()` and `count` should be replaced with `strlen` also `$pw` is never set

Comment: @MA42 :) . If you write such a comment you should also post a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
//Allowed array of parameters
$allowed = array('birth','gender','username','passwordw','email','lang');

$cont=true;
//Loop through the post and check & assign the variables
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(in_array($key,$allowed) && $value!=''){
        //m or f set $cont to false if not
        if($key=='gender' && ($value!='m' || $value!='f')){$arr['Code'] = 420; $cont=false;}
        //chek if email set $cont to false if not
        if($key=='email' && filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED)==true){$arr['Code'] = 419; $cont=false;}
        //check pass len set $cont to false if not
        if($key=='password' && strlen($value)==32){$arr['Code'] = 423; $cont=false;}
        //Assign the variable
        $$key=$value;
    }else{
        //Rouge key in post or value blank
        $cont=false;
    }
}

//if alls ok
if($cont===true){

    $code = genverification();

    //PDO connect to database
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOURDB", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    //Use prepared statement to avoid sql injections
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT into USER
            (DATE_BIRTH,GENDER,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL,VERIFICATION) 
             VALUES (:birth,:gender,:username,:password,:email,:code)');

    //bind the variables to the parameters
    $sth->bindParam(':birth', $birth, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($birth));
    $sth->bindParam(':gender', $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
    $sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($username));
    $sth->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($password));
    $sth->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($email));
    $sth->bindParam(':code', $code, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($code));
    $sth->execute();

    //Do your mail
    require_once("mailer.php");
    if (sendmail($email,$link, $lang)){
        $arr['Code'] = 200;
    }else{
        $arr['Code'] = 422;
    }
}else{
    #Show your errors
}
?>
```

Comment: yeah thx for your answer but the code is too difficult for me (i am used to code in java)

Comment: np, tho im surprised you say that as java is more strict

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of possibilities, if you dare, try [while + break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) :-

```
$success = null;
while (empty($error))
{
  if (...)
  {
    $error = xxx;
    break;
  }
  // repeat other checking
  // lastly
  $sql = ...;
  if ( $insert_ok )
  {
    $success = ...;
    break;
  }
}

if ( ! empty($error))
{
   //  something error
}
if ( ! empty($success))
{
  // something right
}
```

Other [control strucutures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) in PHP

Comment: i always heard the everyone should avoid breaks